# Change footnotes style in Word 2016 (switch from superscript to normal text)

Tags: ms-word, formatting

I need to change the footnote style in MS Word 2016.
I'd like to have the number between round brackets as shown in the image and in normal text (not superscript).

[image]

Both in the text and in the footnote area of the page.

[image]

I've tried to do a "replace all" of "**^f**" with "**(^&)**" and it works but it doesn't convert occurrences to normal text, they still remain in superscript :(

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Find and Replace
2. Type ^f in the **Find What** text box
3. Type (^&) in the **Replace With** text box
4. Click on **More**
5. When you are still in the Replace With text box click **Font** and
   untick **SuperScript**.

The Find What Format will then be blank and the Replace With Format will then be Not Superscript/Subscript.

6. Click Replace all.

Answer (score 1):

- Click in the Replace box;
- Press More and the Format button;
- Choose Font;
- Click the Superscript option twice to specify and then remove
  this formatting.

[This isn't a coding question, though, unless you intend to achieve it with code. In which case, record a macro and explore the resultant code.]